# Listbox items become too high for no reason?

Tags: wpf, height, listboxitem

Hello the screenshot explains it:
[image]

Why are do the Items become so tall? I do no positioning myself:

```
    <ListBox Margin="6" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=Segments}">
    </ListBox>
```

No ItemTemplate either I'm relying on default `ToString()` behaviour.

Comment: Just guessing, but sometimes certain weird Unicode characters can cause the line height to go up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I found the problem. Each Line is surrounded by newline characters.

I didn't see it immediately because the data is returned via IPC call from external program.